# Additional null bytes in DNS response packet

Tags: dns, udp

I am new user, so hello everybody. I am facing with below problem.

**Short description:** I have device, which is connected to my ISP network. On that device I am running custom DNS service (it simply forwards DNS queries from LAN to ISP DNS server and received answers back to LAN). My ISP blocks some sites, so when you are trying reach one of them (e.g. xhamster.com), you will be redirected to warning page.

**Problem:** When I run host command (on my device) for blocked site, I should get IP address of warning page (e.g. 1.2.3.4). Unfortunately it doesn't happen, because my DNS service discards packet received from ISP DNS server. Looking on traffic, which comes to / from my device I found out that, when I ask for blocked site, ISP DNS server in reply packet adds some additional null bytes at the end of it. It isn't happening, when I ask for non blocked site.

**Question:** Is it correct, that DNS server in response packet adds at the end of it few null bytes? I was looking for information inside RFC 1034 and RFC 1035, if such behaviour is correct or not, but I didn't find it.

Thank you in advice.